# как спарсить вложенные контент

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

Cтруктура `HTML`:

```
<div class="responsive">
   <div id="footer_responsive">
     <span id="footerLogo">
       <span id="footerText">
       <span class="valve_links">
       Тут нужный мне контент.
       </span>
       </span>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Парсю через BS4.Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне добраться до нужного мне контента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае нужный контент явно задается с помощью класса, по нему можно сделать поиск.

`print(soup.find("span", class_="valve_links").text)`

Если вам нужно добраться до вложенного элемента но нет индификаторов для тега, но вам известен его порядок - можно сделать так

`print(soup("span")[n].text)` - этот код найдет n-ый корневой span и выведет весь вложенный текст в него.

А вообще.. надо [документацию](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/BeautifulSoup) читать. Там много полезной информации

Comment: Это работает, спасибо.Сегодня часа два потратил, писал такой же код,но выводило Null или пустой список.Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Если хотите можете спрашивать у меня лично,

vk.com/qooke

Answer (score 3):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
html = """
<div>
   <div>
     <span>
       <span>
       Тут нужный мне контент.
       </span>
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
"""
soup = BS(html)
print(soup.div.div.span.span.text)
```

Comment: А если будет несколько span`ов( не вложенных друг в друга) ?

Comment: Присвойте ему класс :)